# ¿Tamaño de una tabla en SQL Server es igual en Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

El tamaño ocupado en una tabla, es el mismo en Oracle que en SQL Server ?, por ejemplo si una tabla pesa 150MB, será de igual tamaño en ambos sistemas?

Comment: SQL es simplemente un lenguaje para consultar bases de datos relacionales.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a SQL Server?

Comment: Una disculpa, ya corregí. Saludos

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia, y no hay una respuesta definitiva. Depende de muchos factores. Francamente, lo mas sencillo es que lo pruebes tu mismo para ver en qué tamaño resulta.

Answer (score 0):

Hace un tiempo pase información de un Ms Sql Server 2008 a Oracle 10g y los tamaños eran muy similares siendo algo mas grande en Oracle. La verdad no me fije 
con detalle y ya los sistemas han variado y no son comparables. Quizás le sirva de referencia

Answer (score 0):

Dependera de la informacion, de los tipos de datos en las tablas (Origen y destino)  y de si tienes habilitada la compresion en uno y otro lado.